# What was the ethno-linguistic makeup of the Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth?

Tags: europe, poland, early-modern, poland-lithuania

What was the ethno-linguistic makeup of the [Rzeczpospolita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rzeczpospolita), that is, the [Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish%E2%80%93Lithuanian_Commonwealth) prior to the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitions_of_Poland)?

EDIT: Clarification, asking what were the percentages to total population of the various ethnic/linguistic groups.

Comment: Is Rz pronounced like z in azure?

Comment: @SnackExchange In Russian, Rzeszów is Жешув, which sounds similar to the way the Poles pronounce it. Thus, if you know how the Russians pronounce the Ж...

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Oh, fortunately I'm familiar with Russian alphabet. So it is indeed pronounced like azure ;-)

Comment: Mainly Lithuanians and Polish... I think the question needs to be more precise.

Comment: @SnackExchange Yes. "rz" and also "ż" are pronounced this way, a soft "rz". There's a "hard" version spelled "ź" or "zi".

Comment: @Spencer It's pretty hard, actually. Ź / zi is a different, softer sound.

Comment: RZ/ż is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_fricative   zi/Ź is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_alveolo-palatal_fricative

IPA is your firend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what [New World Encyclopedia](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Polish-Lithuanian_Commonwealth#Demographics_and_religion) states, shortly after the [Truce of Deuolino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truce_of_Deulino) (1619):

- 4,5m Poles
- 3,5m Ukrainians
- 1,5m Belarussians
- 0,75m Lithuanians
- 0,75m Prussians
- 0,5m Jews
- 0,5m Livonians

[image]

Livonians here mean inhabitants of Polish-Lithuanian Livonia which included Latvians, Estonians, Baltic Germans and Livs.

Answer (score 5):

It was very diverse. It contained Poles (who spoke Polish), ancestors of modern Ukrainians and Belarussians (who spoke in various dialects, which later became Ukrainian and Belarussian languages),
they were called Ruthenians at that time, Lithuanians, Germans, Jews (speaking Yiddish and using Hebrew for religious purposes), Tatars (with their own languages), Armenians, Karaites and several other ethnic groups, smaller in numbers. I think I listed
all largest groups.

The (English) Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish%E2%80%93Lithuanian_Commonwealth#Languages) has a list of languages, and marks which of them were officially recognized. In addition to those I listed, Latin was an officially recognized language. For the sources, the mentioned Wikipedia article contains a lot of them, and I can add the books of Timothy Snyder.

Comment: There were substantial Tatar groups living in Lithuania.

Comment: They are not necessarily related. The word "Tatars" in Eastern Europe could denote any group of Muslim religion or a group speaking a Turkic language. For example Crimean Tatars.

Comment: @justCal: Thanks. I've done it.